# \clearpage no funciona en LaTeX

Tags: latex

Quiero dejar una página en blanco después del título, y otra, después de la lista de tablas, tal como aparece detallado a continuación.

```
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents 
    \addtocounter{page}{-1} 
    \pagenumbering{roman} 
    \newpage
    \listoffigures
    \newpage
    \listoftables
    \clearpage
```

Sin embargo, la función `\clearpage` no funciona. No se que puede ser, ya que no aparece ningún error. Es posible que LaTeX esté interpretando que se lleva a cabo correctamente la función?

Adjunto lista de paquetes:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Escribir en castellano.
\usepackage{mathptmx }%Adobe Times Roman (or equivalent) as default font
\usepackage{titlesec} %Selection from various title styles
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=3.5cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} %control de tamaño de papel y márgenes
\usepackage{graphicx} %para poder incluir figuras 
\usepackage{siunitx} %para notación científica
\usepackage{float} %complemento para figura
\usepackage{import} %para poder dividir el texto en varios archivos
\usepackage{natbib} %para la bibliografía
\usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing %Control del espacio entre lineas
\usepackage{xcolor} %Para cambiar el color de texto
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para añadir una página puedes hacerlo sustituyendo tu `\clearpage` por lo siguiente:

```
\newpage\null\newpage
```

El comanod `\clearpage` funciona igual que `\newpage` con la salvedad de que el primero limpia los *floats* que tengas hasta ese momento (más información [aquí](https://latexref.xyz/_005cclearpage-_0026-_005ccleardoublepage.html)), por lo tanto en el código de antes puedes usar uno u otro indistintamente.